# How many of the numbers are consecutive in a string

Tags: r, numbers, sequence

Having this vector:

```
vector <- c("236", "234", "", "12", "24", "3")

[1] "236" "234" ""    "12"  "24"  "3"
```

I would like to check how many consecutive numbers there are in each element.

Expected output:

```
2 3 0 2 0 0
```

I have no idea how to do this!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possible solution:

```
sapply(strsplit(vector,""),
       function(x) {s <- sum(diff(as.numeric(x))==1); 
                    if (s) {s+1} else 0})

[1] 2 3 0 2 0 0
```

Answer (score 4):

I guess this does the job:

```r
vector <- c("236", "234", "", "12", "24", "3")

sapply(strsplit(vector, ""), function(x) {
  r <- rle(diff(as.numeric(x) - seq(length(x))))
  if(0 %in% r$values) max(r$lengths[r$values == 0]) + 1 else 0
})
#> [1] 2 3 0 2 0 0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Another option

```
library(matrixStats)
v1 <- rowSums(rowDiffs(as.matrix(read.fwf(textConnection(paste(vector,
   collapse = "\n")), widths = rep(1, 3)))) == 1, na.rm = TRUE)
replace(v1, v1 != 0, v1[v1!=0] + 1)
[1] 2 3 0 2 0 0
```